# Importing SVG image results in Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server:

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I installed file-loader in my next.js project and configured my next.config.js to be like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    webpack: config => {
        const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                    },
                },
            ],
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

I then have an image in `/public/images/book-reading.svg`

So I tried to import the image like this in a component I have within `/src/components`:

```
import BookReading from '../../public/images/book-reading.svg';
```

And using it like this:

```
 <img src={BookReading} />
```

However the image does not show and I get this warning:

> Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server:
> "images/364068d183bb962a8423031f65bab6ad-book-reading.svg" Client:
> "/_next/images/364068d183bb962a8423031f65bab6ad-book-reading.svg"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `publicPath` and the `outputPath` to file-loader's options.

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                        publicPath: `/_next/static/images/`,
                        outputPath: 'static/images',
                    },
                },
            ],
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

This is not your case but for the sake of completeness: if you had used a different [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath), you'd have needed to add it at the beginning of your `publicPath`.

[Source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12810#discussioncomment-93366)

Comment: outputPath and publicPath did it for me